# What's the proper way to use an Objective-C category within Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode6

I'm trying to import some category methods into my Swift file without any luck.

**ios-Bridging-Header.h:**

```
#import "UIColor+Hex.h"
```

**UIColor+Hex.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIColor (Hex)

+ (UIColor *)colorWithHex:(NSUInteger)hexInt;
+ (UIColor *)colorWithHexString:(NSString *)hexString;

@end
```

I would expect the autocomplete to reveal `UIColor(hexInt: NSUInteger)` and `UIColor(hexString: String)`

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Extensions.html

Comment: I have got a couple of questions about your code: In your bridging header should it not be "#import" instead of "import" rather? Which line did you write to finally import your category in Swift?

Comment: Yep, typo in my question. The code I accepted below worked well for me!

Comment: See my new answer below. Basically you need a bridging header: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: I'm trying to use NSAttributedString extension (cocopods), i've added them in bridging header file as well but same issue as yours. I expect autocomplete to reveal the methods but it's not.. Pods i'm using is from: https://github.com/dbowen/NSAttributedString-DDHTML
Thanks,

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Actually, your category is transtlated to Swift as follows:

```
extension UIColor {

    init(hex hexInt: Int) -> UIColor

    init(hexString: String) -> UIColor

}
```

And because of that, you should be using:

```
let color = UIColor(hex: 0xffffff) // instead of hexInt:

let color = UIColor(hexString: "ffffff")
```

Autocompletion may still be buggy in the beta software, though.

Comment: 3 years later... autocompletion is still buggy.

Answer (score 25):

You can use Objective-C categories directly in Swift. This gets really interesting for some of the bridged classes, like String. Extend NSString with a category in Objective-C, and then you can access it from Swift (directly on String!)

The way to do this is by creating a "bridging header" in your Swift project.

Full instructions [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html).

The short of it is:

1. Make a .h header file (in Objective-C) with all the other `#import` statements in it
2. Put the path to that file in `Objective-C Bridging Header` in your Build Settings
3. No need to import the bridging header in your Swift file. It's already there

Comment: but the problem is this category will be available in all swift file, however in ObjC we can use in file where actually it is required

Comment: @MayankJain more importantly, in Objective-C you can choose between different categories that have similar method names. However, this is probably a good way to shoot yourself in the foot... perhaps Swift it ultimately on the right side of this thing.

Comment: @DanRosenstark agreed...!!! In one of my project it is my requirement to import category file in specific file, I wanted other files should use original implementation and only specific file can use custom category. Category is written in ObjC.