# Accessing the frontmost controller of an iOS App

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to access the frontmost controller of the Application during the user navigation using this code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    println(UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController)

}
```

But it seems that the `rootViewController` always refers to the first controller defined by the storyboard independently by when I'm accessing that property.

Is there something I'm doing wrong or I've misunderstood about the `rootViewController` property?

Comment: Do you mean the first view controller in the navigation stack?

Comment: If you're using a UINavigationController, you can just use the topViewController property. (e.g., self.navigationController.topViewController).

Comment: is a viewController presented modally, but I need to access it from a test (XCTest)

Answer (score 1):

`rootViewController` is indeed [the topmost, ultimate view controller owned by UIWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131205/iphone-how-to-find-topmost-view-controller).

To get the currently displaying view controller, you need to walk down the controller hierarchy.  [Here is an Objective-C ***category*** that you can add to your application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21848247/981049), and [using a bridging header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24064627/whats-the-proper-way-to-use-an-objective-c-category-within-swift) you'll easily be able to call this UIWindow category from your swift code.

Answer (score 0):

OK, based on the code that Michael pointed out, I wrote some Swift (1.2) code to do the same thing. You can add this as an extension to UIViewController (as I did), UIApplication, or for that matter simply make it a global function.

```
extension UIViewController {

    static func getVisibleViewController () -> UIViewController {
        let rootViewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController

        return getVisibleViewControllerFrom(rootViewController!)
    }

    static func getVisibleViewControllerFrom(viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController {
        let vcToReturn: UIViewController

        if let navController = viewController as? UINavigationController {
            vcToReturn = UIViewController.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(navController.visibleViewController)
        }
        else if let tabBarController = viewController as? UITabBarController {
            vcToReturn = UIViewController.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(tabBarController.selectedViewController!)
        }
        else {
            if let presentedViewController = viewController.presentedViewController {
                vcToReturn = UIViewController.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(presentedViewController)
            }
            else {
                vcToReturn = viewController
            }
        }

        return vcToReturn
    }

}
```

You'd call this in the following way:

```
let visibleViewController = UIViewController.getVisibleViewController()
```

Hope this helps.

Andrew

PS I haven't tried this in Swift 2.0 yet, so I can't guarantee it will work without issues there. I know it won't work (as written) in Swift 1.1 or 1.0.