# Making the UIButton hit area larger than the default hit area

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

I'm trying to make the hit area of a UIButton larger.

I tried using:

```
myButton.setHitTestEdgeInsects
```

but Xcode doesn't recognise it.

I also tried:

```
myButton.contentEdgeInsets = (UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5))
```

but it changes the look of my button.

Im using swift so for I added the necessary files to the import header.
i guess the problem is there. Can someone help with that or tell about a similar swift function? here is the func im trying to use -

Edit - I think i'm getting closer to the solution 
because im writing in swift xcode recognised it like that

```
 myButton.hitTestEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-200, -200, -200, -200)
```

instead of -

```
 myButton.setHitTestEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-200, -200, -200, -200)
```

so now xcode recognises it but still i have no change in my hit area..

Comment: Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: If you want to increase the size, it should be `UIEdgeInsetsMake(-5, -5, -5, -5)`

Comment: `setHitTestEdgeInsects` is not a native implementation, rather a category on UIButton as found in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13067285/2043580

Comment: but it only increases the size and location of the button. i want the button to look the same only to increase the hit location to be also where the title of the button is located (above the button)

Comment: Do you know how to include a category in XCode?

Comment: ZeMoon - i already read this answer and imported the files. it still does not recognize setHitTestEdgeInsects. am i missing something? after i imported i tried

Comment: mybutton.setHitTestEdgeInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(-10, -10, -10, -10)) but xcode does not recognize setHitTestEdgeInsets

Comment: no i don't know please explain

Comment: If XCode is not recognizing the method, then it's a problem with how the category was created. Look up a tutorial on how to do the same.

Comment: im using swift so I imported it in the import header

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24064627/whats-the-proper-way-to-use-an-objective-c-category-within-swift

Comment: I read that and still don't get whats wrong.. thanks for all the help

Comment: please see my edit above . i got xcode to recognise the function but i get no change in my hit area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why did you simple create a custom button which are at the size you want for your hit box but include a margin inside it's content ?

Or may be with a `UIEdgeInsets` put on your button, your button will have a margin so the hit box seems bigger than button with this solution..

Comment: because i need my button to be small and when using UIEdgeInsets my buttons image changes

Comment: Yes, if you applie a UIEdgeInsets positive you will have a margin inside your button, and so your button will be more smaller than the hit box

Comment: please see my edit above . i got xcode to recognise the function but i get no change in my hit area