# UIImage+ResizeMagick | NSInvalidArgumentException | iOS | Swift

Tags: ios, uiimage, objective-c-category

I'm using "UIImage+ResizeMagick" (iOS api by some developer for resizing image written in obj-c) in my swift project, but facing issues and getting the following error:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage resizedImageByMagick:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe74c2065c0'**

I know this error occurs when that function doesn't exists in that particular class or if we pass wrong parameters while calling the function but i don't think it's the case with my code (if i'm not wrong)

This class is written as: **"UIImage(ResizeMagick)"** and as per my knowledge it's a category so i can use the methods with every UIImage object. I've imported it in my class as **#import "UIImage+ResizeMagick.h"** and using it as:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"validate-icon-tick.png"];
image = [image resizedImageByMagick:@"200x200"];
```

I'm using multiple libraries in my project that are written in obj-c but i'm using bridging header for this purpose. May be the problem with ResizeMagick is because of extensions vs categories difference in obj-c and swift. 
Kindly tell me what i'm doing wrong or if is it possible or not. Thanks.

Comment: control click on `resizedImageByMagick` and see it it takes you to the interface of the catagory file. check and comment plz

Comment: @Sehab Roy, In UIImage (ResizeMagick), Method decleration is as:
    - (UIImage *) resizedImageByMagick: (NSString *) spec;

Comment: So after control clicking you are getting navigated there.

Comment: Do you have any other instance variable in the name of `image` or check if you have copied the catagory classes properly or not, delete them and copy them once again

Comment: Yes.. I am able to do this.

Comment: @Sahed Roy, i've tried with different names of image + have also copied them. But nothing good...
FYI: i've copied the library code (of UIImage(ResizeMagick) by using the following steps:
BuildPhases -> CopyBundleResources -> tap on + sign -> Add folder

Comment: Just drag and drop the classes to your navigator and check the tickmark "Copy items if needed" , add it like this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89550/discussion-between-fyza-nawaz-and-saheb-roy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue for using extension (cocopods) in swift.

I've added `#import <UIImage-ResizeMagick/UIImage+ResizeMagick.h>` in my **bridging header** file. In controller i've used the methods of this extension as:

`let image = oldImage.resizedImageByMagick("200x200")`

**Extensions vs Categories** (in swift and objective-c) are well explained over here:[stack overflow post link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24064627/whats-the-proper-way-to-use-an-objective-c-category-within-swift/24064809#24064809)