# How to connect ObjC file with the + sign in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, syntax

When I have an ObjC file like "filename.m", I connect it with:

```
let a = Filename()
```

but how can I connect if the filename is - "filename+another.m"?

Comment: that Filename() isnt actually the filename, its the class name, and the filename+another.m is usally for the extension of the the first file. can you paste the filename+other.m ?

Comment: As Dejan says, you're confusing some concepts here. A "filename+another.m" file would typically be the code for an Objective C "[category](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html)", an extension to an existing class. For Swift you'd [import the Objective C header file for the category](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27591774/300836).

Comment: @DejanSkledar https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/blob/master/Extensions/XEP-0012/XMPPIQ%2BLastActivity.m this file

Comment: So the class is actually called `XMPPIQ`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you have the `XMPPIQ` Framework. And you declare your variable of type `XMPPIQ` like this:

```
var test: XMPPIQ = XMPPIQ()
```

And then you want to add the `XMPPIQ+LastActivity.h` which isn't a framework nor a class, its an **Extension** for the class `XMPPIQ`.

To access the code/methods from that extension, you connect the Obj-C files as usual in the Bridging header, and then just do:

```
let lastActivity:NSInteger = test.lastActivityQueryTo... // Method from XMPPIQ+LastActivity.m
```

And don't forget to add the `XMPPIQ+LastActivity` **.m** and **.h** files.